# React JS error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm attempting to populate a drop-down box with data consumed from an API; The data in this drop-down box is reflected according to data populated from another drop-down box.

This is my code and where the error occurs:

```
fetchSimulation(building) {
  const bearerToken = this.getToken();

  fetch(`http://www.myAPI.com/${param.data}`, {method: 'GET',headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
  },}).then(results => results.json()).then(simulation => {
    this.setState({ segments: simulation.segments, selected: simulation.segments[0].segmentName })
    this.props.onSelect(simulation.segments[0])
  });
}
```

Error line:

```
this.setState({ segments: simulation.segments, selected: simulation.segments[0].segmentName })
              this.props.onSelect(simulation.segments[0])
```

I have two questions: 
Question 1: Could there be a syntax issue in the approach am using to pass parameters via the URL in my Fetch? 
Question 2: The server my API is hosted on, I also notice that it constantly crashes / go down for about 25-40 minutes and then it's back up. I notice this occurs 3-4 minutes after running my APP. I'm very new to React JS, but could my code be cause of the server going down (is it possible, for example memory leak)?

Comment: Can you log simulation object to see what exactly the data structure you are getting

Comment: what is `results.json()` ?